Issue with Top N expression within Power BI if filtering via another table
I have created code to display the Top 10 N Manufacturers along with a grouped up "Other" Category using a Pseudo Table.
Everything was well with the world until I attempted to filter via another table that is in a one to many relationship (both way filtering).
I've tried so many variations, no colleague has been able to help either.
Here is the code that makes the Pseudo table: Pseudo Manufacturer Table = UNION(DISTINCT(All_Areas_Vehicles[Manufacturer]), DATATABLE("Manufacturer", STRING,{{"Others"}}))
And here is the original code I used to reflect the Top 10, Plus putting the rest into an "Other" Category:
Top N Manufacturer = 
VAR TopManTable = 
TOPN(
    10,
    ALLSELECTED('Pseudo Manufacturer Table'),
    [Count_Manufacturer]
    )

 VAR TopManuCount = 
 CALCULATE(
    [Count_Manufacturer],
 KEEPFILTERS(TopManTable)
 )

 VAR OtherManu = 
 CALCULATE(
    [Count_Manufacturer],
 ALLSELECTED('Pseudo Manufacturer Table')
 ) - 
 CALCULATE(
    [Count_Manufacturer],
     TopManTable
     )

 VAR CurrentManu = SELECTEDVALUE('Pseudo Manufacturer Table'[Manufacturer])

 RETURN
 IF(
    CurrentManu <> "Others", 
 TopManuCount,
  OtherManu   
   )

Finally here is the latest code that I've created to try and make the filters from the other table not impact this:
Top N Manufacturer = 
VAR TopNCount = 10

-- Calculate the top N manufacturers
VAR TopManTable = 
    TOPN(
        TopNCount,
        ALLSELECTED('Pseudo Manufacturer Table'[Manufacturer]),
        [Count_Manufacturer]
    )

-- Calculate the count for the top N manufacturers
VAR TopManuCount = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX(
            TopManTable,
            [Count_Manufacturer]
        )
    )

-- Calculate the total count of manufacturers, considering all filters
VAR TotalManuCount = 
    CALCULATE(
        [Count_Manufacturer],
        REMOVEFILTERS('Pseudo Manufacturer Table'[Manufacturer])
    )

-- Calculate the count for the "Others" category
VAR OtherManuCount = 
    TotalManuCount - TopManuCount

-- Get the currently selected manufacturer
VAR CurrentManu = SELECTEDVALUE('Pseudo Manufacturer Table'[Manufacturer])

RETURN
    IF(
        ISBLANK(CurrentManu),
        BLANK(),
        IF(
            CurrentManu = "Others", 
            OtherManuCount,
            IF(
                CONTAINS(TopManTable, 'Pseudo Manufacturer Table'[Manufacturer], CurrentManu),
                [Count_Manufacturer],
                BLANK()
            )
        )
    )

I just cannot workout why applying a filter from the other table is making the "Others" Category disappear, I'm getting desperate here as I've spend around 6 hours trying to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
